# How can I perform a threadsafe point-in-time snapshot of a key-value map in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, concurrency

In my application, I have a key-value map that serves as a central repository for storing data that is used to return to a defined state after a crash or restart (checkpointing).

The application is multithreaded and several threads may put key-value pairs into that map. One thread is responsible for regularly creating a checkpoint, i. e. serialize the map to persistant storage.

While the checkpoint is being written, the map should remain unchanged. It's rather easy to avoid new items being added, but what about other threads changing members of "their" objects inside the map?

I could have a single object whose monitor is seized when the checkpointing starts and wrap all write access to any member of the map, and members thereof, in blocks synchronizing on that object. This seems very error-prone and tedious to me.

I could also make the map private to the checkpointer and only put copies of the submitted objects in it. But then I would have to ensure that the copies are deep copies and I wouldn't be able to have the data in the map being automatically updated, on every change to the submitted objects, the submitters would have to re-submit them. This seems like a lot of overhead and also error-prone, as I have to remember putting resubmit code in all the right places.

What's an elegant and reliable way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgras is right that immutability would fix things, but that would also be tough. You could just lock the whole thing but that could be a performance problem. I can think of two good ideas.

First is to use a [ReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) (which requires 1.5 or newer). Since your checkpoint can acquire the read lock it can be assured things are safe, but when no one is reading performance should be pretty good. This is still a pretty coarse lock, so you may also want to do #2...

Second is to break things up. Each area of the program could keep it's own map (the map for GUI stuff, the map for user settings, the map for hardware settings, whatever). Each one would have a lock on it and things would go about as usual. When it came time to checkpoint, the checkpointer would grab ALL the locks (so things are consistant) and then do it's job. The catch here is you have define an order for the locks to be grabbed in (say alphabetical) otherwise you'll end-up with deadlocks.

If the maps are orthogonal to each other (updates to one don't require updates to another to be consistent) then the easiest thing may be to push the updates to a central "backup" map in the checkpointer, not unlike something you described.

My biggest question to you would be, how much of a problem is this (performance wise)? Are updates very frequent, or are they rare? That would help to advise on something since my last idea (previous paragraph) could be slow, but it's easy and may not matter.

There is a fantastic book called [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) which is basically the Java threading bible. It discusses how to figure out this kind of stuff and strategies to avoid problems or make solving them easier. If you are going to be doing more threading, it's a very useful read.

Actually if your key values are orthogonal to eachother, then things are really easy. The [ConcurrentMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface (there are implemetations such as the [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) would solve your problems since they can do changes atomically, so readers wouldn't see inconsistent data. But if you have any two (or more) keys that must be updated at the same time this won't cover you.

I hope this helps. Threading access to shared data structures is complex stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> what about other threads changing members of "their" objects inside the map

Here you have a problem :) and it cannot be solved by any kind of Map...

One solution would be to allow only immutable objects in your Map, but this may be impossible for you.

Otherwise you have to share a lock will all threads that may change data referenced by your map and block them all during your snapshot ; but this is a stop the world approach...

Comment: +1 immutable objects, the map is snapshot of state. Work out your clone/serialization and remember to read about the transient keyword